# How can I make a method take an array of any type as a parameter?

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to be able to take in any array type as a parameter in a method.:

```
public void foo(Array[] array) {
    System.out.println(array.length)
}
```

Is there a way where I could pass a String[] or int[] array, in the same method?

Comment: Make it generic. Then you could declare it as accepting a collection of whatever type you desire.

Comment: No, you could make the method generic to pass an array of type T, but for primitive arrays, you'll have to overload it.

Comment: Changing the method to generic solved the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

```
public <T>void foo(T[] array) {
    System.out.println(array.length);
}
```

This will not work for array of primitive types, such as `int[]`, `boolean[]`, `double[]`,... You have to use their class wrappers instead: `Integer[]`, `Boolean[]`, `Double[]`, ... or overload your method for each needed primitive type separately.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can do something like this (because an array is an Object) -

```
public static int getArrayLength(Object array) {
    return Array.getLength(array);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3 };
    String[] stringArray = { "1", "2", "c", "d" };
    System.out.println(getArrayLength(intArray));
    System.out.println(getArrayLength(stringArray));
}
```

Output is

```
3
4
```

Comment: But this solves only a very specific case of calculating the array length. What would you do if you wanted to do *something else* with the passed array? :)

Comment: @HonzaZidek Use the other (static) methods in [Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html); for example `Array.get(array, 0)`.

Comment: I did not know this. How fast is it compared with the standard array usage? `T var = Array.get(array, 0)` vs. `T var = array[0]`? And what would you use instead of `T`? If you used `Object`, what would it do in case of arrays of primitive objects? Would it automatically wrapped it? Then I cannot see any advantage over the generics-based solution.

Comment: Every array reference (even a reference on a primitive array) is of type Object (that is, arrays are not primitives themselves - they have a length property for one thing). I didn't say there was any particular advantage to using this, and I expect the performance is the same (but I haven't tested it).

Comment: Sure, but `get(Object array, int index)` returns `Object` even for primitive arrays (as javadoc says, "the value is automatically wrapped in an object if it has a primitive type." So maybe the advantage (for primitive arrays) is that you still may use primitive arrays as parameters, and the autoboxing occurs only inside the method for single array elements.

Comment: @HonzaZidek Yes. That is so. But it doesn't modify the callers reference type. See my example above, using an array of `int`.

Comment: Yes, I edited my previous comment in the meantime :) Maybe you may elaborate your answer more based on our discussion, some people may find it interesting.

Comment: if you think about it, the ONLY reasonable thing you can do with ANY array is request its length or print its class.

Answer (score 3):

It could be possible using Generics.

I you don't know about it I recommend you to read about it in the documentation.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Generics works with Objects so I think you can't pass a String[] and a int[] in the same method. Use Integer[] instead.

Here is the code I would use:

```
public static <K> int  length(K[] array){
    return array.length;
}
```

Also this could work:

```
public static int  length(Object[] array){
    return array.length;
}
```

But it won't allow you to use a specific type of Object instead of Object class.

I'm quite new in this, maybe there is a better solution, but it's the only I know!

Answer (score 0):

As some others have mentioned, there is now way to do this if you want to be able to accept arrays of primitive types as well (unless you are doing something like in Elliott's solution where you only need and Object and can get by only using methods like Array.getLength(Object) that takes an Object as input).

What I do is make a generic method and then overload it for each primitive array type like so:

```
public <T> void foo(T[] array) {
    //Do something
}

public void foo(double[] array) {
    Double[] dblArray = new Double[array.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        dblArray[i] = array[i];
    }
    foo(dblArray);
}
//Repeat for int[], float[], long[], byte[], short[], char[], and boolean[]
```